# Python - syntax error near unexpected token `|'

Tags: python, sh

I am trying to fix the below error for long time but unable to find why this error is triggering. I tried replacing `file` with direct log file name and `day1` is giving total word count of the file.

```
>>> import os
>>> ports =["1080"]
>>> os.chdir("/var/logs")
>>> for i in range(0, len(ports)):
...     file = os.popen("ls -al |grep -i access|grep -w %s.0|awk \'{print $9}\'" %ports[i]).read()
...     day1 = os.popen("sudo cat %s|wc -l" %file).read()
...
 sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
 sh: -c: line 1: `|wc -l'
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer:

Issue is due to whitespaces. Removing the whitespaces fixed the issue.

```
file = os.popen("ls -al |grep -i access|grep -w %s.0|awk \'{print $9}\'" %ports[i]).read().strip()
```

Comment: your quotation mark is wrong. `|' should be '|'

Comment: you shouldn't even use python, if it's only to call `ls`, `grep`, `awk` ... Create a real shell or do it natively in python.

Comment: I don't see I  mentioned this `|' in the code. Am I missing anything here @umutto

Comment: `print "sudo cat %s|wc -l" %x` - check what command exactly you're trying to execute there. *Its syntax is invalid.*

Comment: You rock @deceze thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really a problem with `shell` not `python`. The syntax error is coming from `sh`:

```
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error
```

As you observe, removing the whitespace fixes your problem.

What is happening is that the output of the first `os.popen()` is assigned to `file` as a Python string, and that string includes a terminating newline.
That's because the output of the command includes a terminating newline.

So `file` will be the string `"foo-access.0\n"` or something similar.

That means that the command sent to the second `os.popen()` is

```
sudo cat foo-access.0
| wc -l
```

which is not valid shell syntax (generally, pipe, `|`, cannot begin a line).

Removing the whitespace removes the trailing newline, so the command sent to the second `os.popen()` is

```
sudo cat foo-access.0 | wc -l
```

which is all good.

As others have noted, this script is poor in other ways too.